# python # как увидеть структуру данных команды или запроса

Tags: python, структуры-данных, типы-данных, преобразование

get_tick() - функция возврашаюшая число типа float;
find_last_price_sell() - функция возврашаюшая число типа float;
steps - число типа int

xyz = get_tick() > find_last_price_sell() + steps

Результат: false

---

Как хотелось бы увидеть:

xxx = float - float + int

или :Type

bool = function - function + int

Замечание: по отдельности увидеть какой элемент могу, но хотелось
бы узнать есть ли такая возможность увидеть структуру данных не по отделности, а в таком же разрезе как в команде написано

Comment: в таком виде врятли

Comment: ясно ... Спасибо :/